# Program to check if Magic Square python

Tags: python

I am trying to use python to create a program that will decide based on a text file if a square is a magic square.

```html
def getRowsAndColumns(user2DimensionalList):
  numberOfRows = len(user2DimensionalList)
  numberOfColumns = len(user2DimensionalList[0])
  
  return numberOfRows, numberOfColumns

def getFirstRowSum(user2DimensionalList, numberOfColumns):
  firstRowSum = 0
  
  for currentRowIndex in range(1):
    for currentColumnIndex in range(numberOfColumns):
      firstRowSum = firstRowSum + user2DimensionalList[currentRowIndex][currentColumnIndex]

    return firstRowSum

def hasEqualRowSums(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns):
  rowSum = 0
  
  for currentRowIndex in range(numberOfRows):
    for currentColumnIndex in range(numberOfColumns):
      rowSum = rowSum + user2DimensionalList[currentRowIndex][currentColumnIndex]
    if rowSum != firstRowSum:
      return False
    rowSum = 0
    
  return True

def hasEqualColumnSums(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns):
    columnSum = 0
    for currentColumnIndex in range(numberOfColumns):
      for currentRowIndex in range(numberOfRows):
          columnSum = columnSum + user2DimensionalList[currentRowIndex][currentColumnIndex]
      if columnSum != firstRowSum:
          return False
      columnSum = 0
    
    return True

def hasEqualRowAndColumnSums(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns):
  if hasEqualRowSums(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns) and hasEqualColumnSums(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns):
       return True
  else:
       return False
     
     
def hasFromLeftEqualDiagonalSum(user2DimensionalList, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn, firstRowSum):
  fromLeftDiagonalSum = 0
  
  for currentDiagonalNumberIndex in range(lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn):
    fromLeftDiagonalSum = fromLeftDiagonalSum + user2DimensionalList[currentDiagonalNumberIndex][currentDiagonalNumberIndex]
        
  if fromLeftDiagonalSum != firstRowSum:
    return False
  else:
    return True
  
def hasFromRightEqualDiagonalSum(user2DimensionalList, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn, firstRowSum):
    fromRightDiagonalSum = 0
    currentDiagonalNumberColumnIndex = lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn - 1
    
    for currentDiagonalNumberRowIndex in range(lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn):
        fromRightDiagonalSum = fromRightDiagonalSum + user2DimensionalList[currentDiagonalNumberRowIndex][currentDiagonalNumberColumnIndex]
        currentDiagonalNumberColumnIndex = currentDiagonalNumberColumnIndex - 1
    if fromRightDiagonalSum != firstRowSum:
        return False
    else:
        return True
def hasEqualDiagonalSums(user2DimensionalList, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn, firstRowSum):
    if hasFromLeftEqualDiagonalSum(user2DimensionalList, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn, firstRowSum) and hasFromRightEqualDiagonalSum(user2DimensionalList, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn, firstRowSum):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isLoShuMagicSquare(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn):
    if hasEqualRowAndColumnSums(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns) and hasEqualDiagonalSums(user2DimensionalList, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn, firstRowSum):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    user2DimensionalList = open("input.txt", "r")
    user2DimensionalList = user2DimensionalList.read()
   
    
    
    numberOfRows, numberOfColumns = getRowsAndColumns(user2DimensionalList)
    
    lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn = numberOfRows
    
    firstRowSum = getFirstRowSum(user2DimensionalList, numberOfColumns)
    
    if isLoShuMagicSquare(user2DimensionalList, firstRowSum, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns, lengthOfAnyRowOrColumn):
        print("VALID")
    else:
        print("INVALID")
        
main()
```

Here is what is in my txt file:

```html
4 3 8 9 5 1 2 7 6
8 3 4 1 5 9 6 7 2
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 9 4
6 9 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 3 2 9 4 8 7 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong I get this error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/noahhenkle/Desktop/MagicSquare2.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/noahhenkle/Desktop/MagicSquare2.py", line 91, in main
    firstRowSum = getFirstRowSum(user2DimensionalList, numberOfColumns)
  File "/Users/noahhenkle/Desktop/MagicSquare2.py", line 12, in getFirstRowSum
    firstRowSum = firstRowSum + user2DimensionalList[currentRowIndex][currentColumnIndex]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I am almost certain the code is right but that the txt file is messing everything up.
I included the traceback below.

Comment: Post the whole error message with traceback please.

Comment: I added what you need

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, you read in a bunch of character data, without ever converting to integer.  Then you try to perform arithmetic on the data, starting with an integer value of 0.

At some point, you have to convert your values.  At the moment, you have a 126x1 "2Dim list".  Your attempt to sum the row starts with trying to add `0 + "4"`.

I strongly recommend that you revert to incremental programming.  You posted 100 lines of code without testing the input that feeds the rest of the program.